# C – initialize a two dimensional global static array of structs that contain more than one array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, ini

I want to Initialize a two dimensional global static array of structures that contains arrays in it.
The following doesn’t seems to work.

```
struct MyStuct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c[2];
    int d[2];
};
STATIC MyStuct[2][3] = {
{{1,1,{1,1},{1,1}},
{2,2,{2,2},{2,2}},
{3,3,{3,3},{3,3}}},
{{7,7,{7,7},{7,7}},
{8,8,{8,8},{8,8}},
{9,9,{9,9},{9,9}}}
};
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `doesn’t seems to work.`...how exactly?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think it doesn't compile :)

Comment: @niceman and which compiler does not produce debug message? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
struct MyStuct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c[2];
    int d[2];
};

static struct MyStuct test [2][3] =
{
//            |     COL 0     |  |     COL 1     |  |    COL 2      |
/* ROW 0 */ { {1,1,{1,1},{1,1}}, {2,2,{2,2},{2,2}}, {3,3,{3,3},{3,3}} },
/* ROW 1 */ { {7,7,{7,7},{7,7}}, {8,8,{8,8},{8,8}}, {9,9,{9,9},{9,9}} }
};
```

Your matrix declaration has to use the struct as type, i.e `struct MyStuct test`

Just for test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    struct MyStuct{
        int a;
        int b;
        int c[2];
        int d[2];
    };

    struct MyStuct test [2][3] =
    {
    //            |     COL 0      |       COL 1       |      COL 2        |
    /* ROW 0 */ { {1,1,{1,1},{1,1}}, {2,2,{2,2},{2,2}}, {3,3,{3,3},{3,3}} },
    /* ROW 1 */ { {7,7,{7,7},{7,7}}, {8,8,{8,8},{8,8}}, {9,9,{9,9},{9,9}} }
    };

    for (size_t i=0; i< 2; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            printf("test[%zu][%zu].a = %d\n", i, j, test[i][j].a);
            printf("test[%zu][%zu].b = %d\n", i, j, test[i][j].b);

            for (size_t z=0; z<sizeof(test[i][j].c)/sizeof(test[i][j].c[0]); z++)
            {
                printf("test[%zu][%zu].c[%zu] = %d\n", i, j, z, test[i][j].c[z]);
            }

            for (size_t z=0; z<sizeof(test[i][j].c)/sizeof(test[i][j].c[0]); z++)
            {
                printf("test[%zu][%zu].d[%zu] = %d\n", i, j, z, test[i][j].c[z]);
            }

            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to declare your 2D static global array in proper way, 
i.e.,

```
struct MyStuct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c[2];
    int d[2];
};
static MyStuct arrayName[2][3] = {
    { { 1, 1, { 1 ,1 }, { 1, 1 } },
    { 2, 2, { 2, 2 }, { 2, 2 } },
    { 3, 3, { 3, 3 }, { 3, 3 } } },
    { { 7, 7, { 7, 7 }, { 7, 7 } },
    { 8, 8, { 8, 8 }, { 8, 8 } },
    { 9, 9, { 9, 9 }, { 9, 9 } } }
};
```

The above code is working fine. You can check this